# The matrix ring $M_n(R)$ of a semisimple ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, semi-simple-rings

Suppose that $R$ is a semisimple ring with unity. Let $S=M_n(R)$ be the matrix ring. For simplicity, we proceed with the special case $n=2$. Then, as easily seen,
\begin{align}
S=e_{11}S + e_{22}S,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
e_{11}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\quad, 
e_{22}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
I:=e_{11}S= 
\left\lbrace 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ 
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
: a,b \in R
\right\rbrace.
\end{align}
I guess that $I$ is either simple of semisimple as right $S$-module under the assumption that $R$ is semisimple.

How can I prove this claim?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, for *any* ring $R$ and any integer $n$, the matrix ring $M_n(R)$ of $n$ by $n$ matrices with elements in $R$ is Morita equivalent to $R$, via the idempotent matrix $e$ with a $1$ in position $1,1$ and $0$'s elsewhere. Semi-simplicity is preserved by Morita equivalence. So if $R$ is semi-simple, then so is $M_n(R)$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Morita equivalence. I try to prove the fact that $R$ is semisimple if and only if $M_n(R)$ is semisimple $\forall n \geq 1$. The question I posted is a part of my proof of such a fact. I began with decomposing $S=M_2(R)$ as seen in the post. If each term in the decomposition is simple of even semisimple as an $S$-module, then $S_S$ turns to be semisimple as needed.

Can you help me in proving this? @Stephen